# Outputting linq getting overflow exception

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I'm trying to output a certain answer with matching data using linq. Here's the code,

```
    public string[] netoilVar(string[] final)
    {
        var items = netOil.Zip(seqNum, (oil, seq) => new {Oil = oil, Seq = seq });
        var items2 = netOil2.Zip(seqNum2, (oil, seq) => new { Oil = oil, Seq = seq });

        List<string> vars = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in items2.Join(items, i => i.Seq, i => i.Seq, (a, b) => new
        {
            x = a.Seq,
            y = this.GetTheAnswer(Convert.ToDouble(a.Oil), Convert.ToDouble(b.Oil)),

            oilnum1 = a.Oil,
            oilnum2 = b.Oil,
        }))

        {
            vars.Add(item.y + "," + item.oilnum1 + "," + item.oilnum2);
            final = vars.ToArray();
        }

        return final;
    }

    //BEGINS THE EXECUTE BUTTON METHOD
    private void executeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //NET OIL VARIANCE MATHEMATICS
        if (netOilRadBtn.Checked)
        {
            int i = listHead;
            string[] x = new String[1000]; 

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("testNetOil.csv");

            sw.WriteLine("Lease Name, Field Name, Reservoir, Operator, County, ST, Majo, Resv Cat, Discount Rate, Net Oil Interest, Net Gas Interest, Working Interest, Gross Wells, Ultimate Oil, Ultimate Gas, Gross Oil, Gross NGL, Gross Gas, Net Oil, Net Gas, Net NGL, Revenue To Int., Oper. Expense, Total Invest., Revenue Oil, Revenue Gas, Operating Profit, Revenue NGL, Disc Net Income, SEQ, Well ID, INC ASN, Life Years, Net Oil Variance., Current Year's Net Oil, Last Year's Net Oil");

            //Loops until the end of the list, printing out info
            while (i != -1)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {19}, {20}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {24}, {25}, {26}, {27}, {28}, {29}, {30}, {31}, {32}, {33}, {34}",
                    QuoteString(leaseName[i]), fieldName[i], QuoteString2(reservoir[i]), operator1[i], county[i], state[i], majo[i], resvCatgory[i], disRate[i], netOil2Int[i], netGas2Int[i], workingInt[i], grossWells[i]
                    , ultOil[i], ultGas[i], grossOil[i], grossNGL[i], grossGas[i], netOil[i], netGas[i], netNGL[i], revToInt[i], operExpense[i], totInvest[i], revOil[i], revGas[i], operatingProfit[i],
                revNGL[i], discNetIncome[i], seqNum[i], wellID[i], incASN[i], lifeYears[i], ownQual[i], netoilVar(x)[i]);

                i = pointers[i];
            }
            sw.Close();

        }
```

I'm getting an IndexOutOfRangeException on the while loop that is printing out all the data, most specifically on the netoilVar(x)[I] part. Is there any way I can get the correct index there so I don't get the exception?

Comment: where is `pointers` defined? This is probably the source of your problem. Also why are you using a bunch of arrays instead of a collection of objects?

Comment: @Jay that's just the way I learned how to do it. pointers is defined as int[] pointers = new int[1000];

Comment: Some of that code looks strangely familiar :) I see you're still working mainly with matched arrays, though. You'll find things much easier of you start working with a single _collection_ holding a custom class.

Comment: All that and move `final = vars.ToArray();` below the `foreach` loop. Because you are creating a new array for each element in the array, when it seems like you just want to add all the elements to that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While loops can be dangerous as you have seen here. I would highly recommend abstracting out your data to make things easier to work with.

Model your data like this:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string LeaseName { get; set; }
    public int UltOil { get; set; }
    public int UltGas { get; set; }


    public static string GetHeaders()
    {
        return "LeaseName, UltOil, UltGas";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",", LeaseName, UltOil, UltGas);
    }
}
```

Then when writing out your csv file use the model like this:

```
private void Foo()
{
    //NET OIL VARIANCE MATHEMATICS
    if (netOilRadBtn.Checked)
    {
        var input = new List<MyData>(); // <-- Fill in your data here.

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("testNetOil.csv");

        sw.WriteLine(MyData.GetHeaders());

        //Loops until the end of the list, printing out info
        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(item);
        }

        sw.Close();

    }
}
```

Obviously this is abbreviated, you will want to include all your fields, name and type them appropriately.

Comment: I'm reading in two txt files, how would I substring them to separate the data doing this?

Comment: @Stock: My example above covers the "middle" and "end" of your process. Your question doesn't mention anything about inputs. It would depend on what was in the two inputs, but basically you need to populate instances of `MyData` (named more appropriately) into a collection.